# CNN attention/activation maps

Tags: deep-learning, keras

What are common techniques for finding which parts of images contribute most to image classification **via convolutional neural nets**?

In general, suppose we have 2d matrices with float values between 0 and 1 as entires. Each matrix is associated with a label (single-label, multi-class) and the goal is to perform classification via (Keras) 2D CNN's.

I'm trying to find methods to extract relevant subsequences of rows/columns that contribute most to classification.

Two examples:

https://github.com/jacobgil/keras-cam

https://github.com/tdeboissiere/VGG16CAM-keras

Other examples/resources with an eye toward Keras would be much appreciated.

Note my datasets are not actual images, so using methods with ImageDataGenerator might not directly apply in this case.

Comment: two common ways are, deconvolution(transposed convolution) or image gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many visualization methods. Each of these methods has its strengths and weaknesses.

However, you have to keep in mind that the methods partly visualize different things. Here is a short overview based on this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05598).
You can distinguish between three main visualization groups:

- **Functions** (gradients, saliency map): These methods visualize how a change in input space affects the prediction
- **Signal** (deconvolution, Guided BackProp, PatternNet): the signal (reason for a neuron's activation) is visualized. So this visualizes what pattern caused the activation of a particular neuron.
- **Attribution** (LRP, Deep Taylor Decomposition, PatternAttribution): these methods visualize how much a single pixel contributed to the prediction. As a result you get a heatmap highlighting which pixels of the input image most strongly contributed to the classification.

Since you are asking how much a pixel has contributed to the classification, you should use methods of attribution. Nevertheless, the other methods also have their right to exist.

One nice toolbox for visualizing heatmaps is [iNNvestigate](https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate).
This toolbox contains the following methods:

- [SmoothGrad](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03825)
- [DeConvNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901)
- [Guided BackProp](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6806)
- [PatternNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05598)
- [PatternAttribution](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05598)
- Occlusion
- [Input times Gradient](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01713)
- [Integrated Gradients](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01365)
- [Deep Taylor](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320316303582?via%3Dihub)
- [LRP](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0130140)
- [DeepLift](https://openreview.net/forum?id=Sy21R9JAW)